# Why are we so focused on Zero Coupon Bonds?

Tags: fixed-income, derivatives, zero-coupon, hedge, sensitivities

In fixed income markets there seem to be two prevailing term structure modelling approaches:

1. Market Models
2. HJM Framework

In Market Models, such as the LIBOR Market Model (LMM) and SABR it is common to model market observables such as the Simple Forward Rates (LIBOR rates) or swap rates at different maturities.

In the HJM Framework (and the older short rate models), we instead start from some state variables that can be transformed into the instanteous forward curve and then again transformed into zero coupon bonds and finally linear products. The same goes for short rate models where we start with the dynamics for the short rate and then go through similar steps to get to market rates.

However, in many textbooks and articles the goal seems to be that we should be able to price Zero Coupon Bonds (ZCB). And although they are useful for discounting and can be transformed into market rates, I do not understand why this is the objective.

Generally, ZCB are not traded themselves so we are really interested in libor rates, swap rates, swaps, forward rate agreements, and especially derivatives with one or more of these as the underlying.

Say we have a simple example such as the Vasicek model. We start with the dynamics of the short rate and then find the ZCB and its dynamics. Now, we can easily find linear products / rates. And we may also use that since the short rate is normally distributed then ZCB and many of the linear products are log-normally distributed: Hence, European products can be priced by a Black-formula using the implied volatility.

Let's say that this is a European caplet on a simple forward (LIBOR) rate or a European call on a payer swap. Now, I sell this product and want to hedge it. Can I easily do so?

I do not see how as I would have to either find the dynamics of every underlying that we want to trade a derivative on or rely on Blacks formula and the implied volatility to calculate any market sensitivities (such as "delta" of the caplet, i.e. sensitivities to movements in the underlying LIBOR rate). This does not seem very nice.

So my questions are really:
A) Why are we so focused on ZCB?
B) Is there any clever method / tricks to calculate sensitivities wrt. market observables without either having to rely on Black's formula or derive the dynamics of every underlying in the market?

Comment: I always thought of pricing ZCBs akin to creating an implied vol surface. Traders don't take the ZCB as fact, but use it as a base of market behaviour and then add your own layers and adjustments. It's like going on Bloomberg and seeing the price of interest rates. Like the BS, the Vasicek model is simple and because it has a closed-form solution, it is easy to compute.